# Simple way to center images with equal margin

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to center seven images in a Bootstrap 3 container (red in the image), until the images don't fit next to each other anymore. Now I could hardcode the width of the container and measure the margins etc. or via JavaScript (jQuery).

Is there an easy way to get the following result which also works when the container size changes?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can put the images in a `nav` with `nav-justified`, so that the blocks will be centered. To center the images in the blocks use the following css;

```
.centeredImage {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

you can check the code in http://yuvarla.org/#/partner

hope this helps.